# How to optimize reading and cleaning file?

Tags: python, file, txt

I have a file, which contains strings separated by spaces, tabs and carriage return:

```
one     two

    three

         four
```

I'm trying to remove all spaces, tabs and carriage return:

```
def txt_cleaning(fname):
    with open(fname) as f: 
    new_txt = []
        fname = f.readline().strip()
        new_txt += [line.split() for line in f.readlines()]
    return new_txt
```

Output:

```
[['one'], ['two'], [], ['three'], [], ['four']]
```

Expecting, without importing libraries:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: Regex can split on multiple spaces: `return re.split(r"\s+", f.read())`

Comment: I forgot to specify without importing libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def txt_cleaning(fname):
    new_text = []
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            new_text += [s.strip() for s in line.split() if s]
    return new_text
```

Or

```
def txt_cleaning(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return [word.strip() for word in f.read().split() if word]
```

Answer (score 0):

My method:

- use read (not readline) to get the whole text in a single element
- replace tabs and newlines with a space
- split

```
def txt_cleaning(fname):
  with open(fname) as f:
    return f.read().replace( '\t', ' ').replace( '\n', ' ').split()
```